# Subscripts not showing up in my secondary axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, unicode, subscript

Exactly as the title shows. Trying to use unicode (since brackets are not registering and just showing up as brackets) to create a subscript 2. The mu works fine. The subscripts 2 shows up as an unrecognized character box. Here is the code and an image of what I am talking about. I am open to anything!

[image]

```
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = c(0,4,8,12,16,20), 
      limits = c(0,20), sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*50, 
      breaks = c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000), 
      name = "Hydrogen Sulfide Concentration (\U00B5M H\U2082S)"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expression` and `paste`:

```
name = expression(paste("Hydrogen Sulfide Concentration (", mu, "M H" ["2"], "S)"))
```